# OptaPy quickstart crashing on mac Mini M1

Tags: macos, apple-m1, optapy

Just trying out the OptaPy school timetabling quickstart on a mac Mini with M1 silicon. It crashes with the error message (below). Note that OptaPlanner quickstarts are working on the same machine, so I am ruling out a JDK / JRE issue.

OpenJDK installed via brew

Relevant error message:

```
    #
    # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
    #
    #  SIGBUS (0xa) at pc=0x00000001027fbe30, pid=2724, tid=259
    #
    # JRE version:  (20.0.1) (build )
    # Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (20.0.1, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, bsd-aarch64)
    # Problematic frame:
    # V  [libjvm.dylib+0x367e30]  CodeHeap::allocate(unsigned long)+0x1c0
    #
```

Note that I have been able to run the same without issues on Windows and Ubuntu laptops.

Any help is appreciated.

I was expecting it would work since OptaPlanner, the core of OptaPy works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be related to [a JPype issue](https://github.com/jpype-project/jpype/issues/1143). Once JPype1 has an updated version with a fix for the issue, put the updated version into the `requirements.txt` file (or `pip install JPype1`).

Comment: Thanks. I.was expecting some underlying issues. Will wait for the fix, and update here.

Comment: StackOverflow not allowing me to upvote due to lack of posts :(